# Use AppleScript to get name of application given its bundle identifier (ID)

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript in which I have a list of applications specified by their bundle identifiers (e.g., the bundle of application "TextExpander" is "com.smileonmymac.textexpander").

I want to be able to get the application's *name* from its bundle identifier, e.g., to convert "com.smileonmymac.textexpander" to "TextExpander".

I know how to do the converse:

```
set theAppID to the id of the application "TextExpander"
```

This gives the result:

```
com.smileonmymac.textexpander
```

However, I've been unsuccessful in finding the magical incantation that will go the other direction. For example, I tried:

```
set theAppName to the name of the application whose bundle identifier is "com.smileonmymac.textexpander"
```

but all I get is the error message:

```
error: "Can't get name of application." number -1728 from name of application
```

I've also tried wrapping this between (a) `tell application "System Events"`and (b) `end tell`.

I've tried various other permutations and phrasings, with similar results.

Is there a way to query System Events to get the name of an application that's identified by its bundle ID?

Answer (score 1):

Those are not from System Events, they are [application properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-SW2), so you can do something like:

```
set theAppID to the id of the application "Safari" -- com.apple.Safari, or whatever
set theAppName to name of application id theAppID
```

AppleScriptObjC can also be used, for example:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set theAppID to ((current application's NSBundle's bundleWithPath:(POSIX path of (path to application "Safari")))'s bundleIdentifier) as text -- com.apple.Safari, or whatever
set theAppName to ((current application's NSBundle's bundleWithIdentifier:theAppID)'s objectForInfoDictionaryKey:"CFBundleDisplayName") as text
```